# How to abstract type convertion function properly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-datastore

I have a lot of methods that look like that:

```
override suspend fun getBalance(): Result<BigDecimal> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching balance from data store")
    val balance = balancePreferencesFlow.firstOrNull()
        ?: return@withContext Result.Error(CacheIsInvalidException)

    return@withContext when (balance) {
        is Result.Success -> {
            if ((balance.data.timestamp + ttl) <= getCurrentTime()) {
                deleteBalance()
                Result.Error(CacheIsInvalidException)
            } else {
                resultOf { balance.data.toDomainType() }
            }
        }
        is Result.Error -> balance
    }
}
```

There I am collecting a Flow of some type from DataStore, then if it is a Success Result(with data parameter of type T), I should get its timestamp(it is a data class field), and if the condition is true delete invalid data and if it's false return the converted Result.

The convertion functions look somehow like that:

```
fun BigDecimal.toPersistenceType(): Balance = Balance(
    balanceAmount = this,
    timestamp = getCurrentTime()
)

fun Balance.toDomainType(): BigDecimal = this.balanceAmount
```

I've tried to make an abstract method in this way, but I don't completely understand how I should pass a lambda to it.

```
suspend inline fun <reified T : Any, reified V : Any> getPreferencesDataStoreCache(
    preferencesFlow: Flow<Result<V>>,
    ttl: Long,
    deleteCachedData: () -> Unit,
    getTimestamp: () -> Long,
    convertData: () -> T
): Result<T> {
    val preferencesResult = preferencesFlow.firstOrNull()

    return when (preferencesResult) {
        is Result.Success -> {
            if ((getTimestamp() + ttl) <= getCurrentTime()) {
                deleteCachedData()
                Result.Error(CacheIsInvalidException)
            } else {
                resultOf { preferencesResult.data.convertData() }
            }
        }
        is Result.Error -> preferencesResult
        else -> Result.Error(CacheIsInvalidException)
    }
}
```

And a lambda for convertion should look like an extension method.

The Result class:

```
sealed class Result<out T : Any> {

    data class Success<out Type : Any>(val data: Type) : Result<Type>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

Comment: Can you additionaly post what the `Result<>` class is?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: `convertData: V.() -> T`

Comment: As I see, you are trying to make universal `Result` validation according to some TTL. Moreover return `Error` result instead if it's not valid. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I see here some cache work, that from my point should be placed in one interface.

```
interface Cache {
    val timestamp: Long
    fun clear()
}
```

You can make `timestamp` property nullable to return `null` if your cache is still empty - it's up to you.

Then universal method you need I assume to place inside `Result` class as it seems to be only its own work.

```
sealed class Result<out T : Any> {
    data class Success<out Type : Any>(val data: Type) : Result<Type>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()

    fun <R : Any> convertIfValid(cache: Cache, ttl: Long, converter: (T) -> R) : Result<R> =
            when (this) {
                is Success -> {
                    if (cache.timestamp + ttl <= getCurrentTime()) {
                        cache.clear()
                        Error(CacheIsInvalidException())
                    } else {
                        Success(converter(data))
                    }
                }
                is Error -> this
            }
}
```

May be it would be better to place `getCurrentTime` method in some injected entity too, but it's not important in this post.
By the way, as you can see here in `when` I didn't place `else` state as it is unnecessary for sealed classes.

From your code I can make an example of cache implementation only for balance:

```
class BalanceCache : Cache {
    var balanceValue = Balance()
    override val timestamp: Long
        get() = balanceValue.timestamp

    override fun clear() {
        deleteBalance()
    }
}
```

If you need more examples from me, please give me more details about your code where you want to use it.